# Enabling bluetooth on Android device (LGP500)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-activity

I've generated a new project inside Eclipse IDE with help of the ADT plugin. Next, I added an intent for enabling Bluetooth in the `onCreate` method of my main activity (the only activity). I also added BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions and set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

Now if I start my application the Bluetooth request dialog comes up many times (if you constantly say 'no' to the dialog). I could imagine that this is because of the activity life cycle and screen orientation changes. It seems strange to me because I explicitly set screen orientation to landscape.

Then I added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. Now my `onCreate` method is called only once, that's for sure, because I see my logs! But the dialog comes up twice!  And what is also interesting I always get one `onActivityResult` callback.

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong in my application/my understanding? What should I do to present to the user the request Bluetooth dialog only once?

Comment: My expirience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873564/bluetooth-activation-alert-dialog-multiplication-after-screen-rotation that partially explain some of the issues you observe.

Comment: Hi, Zelimir! Well, I think this is exactly the same issue. At least when I read your post I "saw" my troubles =) Although, my phone is running android 2.2.1 (LGP500).

Comment: I reported issue at the Android developers site but did not get any response. So, unfortunatelly, I cannot help further. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

try to use *onStart()* method of your activity